# Can you recommend a standard, cool environment for Java web application coding?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts

I'm a beginner coding a Java web application.  I used to code Ruby On Rails.

Can you recommend a standard, cool environment for Java web application coding? Is Java+Tomcat+Struts+Eclipse standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say your choices of Java (duh), Eclipse (Netbeans is also a viable option for IDE) and Tomcat are pretty non-controversial.

Struts was a good framework for MVC web applications, but I think it may be a bit dated these days - Spring seems to be the primary heir apparent in that category. However, if you're jumping onto a whole new language and platform I would suggest leaving an MVC framework out of the mix at first and just coding basic servlets or JSPs by hand. Once you have those basic technologies down, then you can get into fancier frameworks.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I coding basic servlets. I should only use Apache Tomcat Eclipse ?

Comment: Tomcat is the reference implementation for a servlet container, so... yes, Tomcat (distributed by Apache) is probably the best choice for learning servlets. Eclipse is not Apache/Tomcat, it's an independently-distributed IDE. However, you can find plugins for Eclipse that allow you to deploy to and control Tomcat through Eclipse, which can be a time-saver.

Comment: I get it! I'll code with Eclipse IDE with Tomcat plugin. and I should make envronment Tomcat + Apache.

Comment: +1 Learning Struts or any other web framework can be a *long* process.

Comment: IntelliJ has a free edition and IMO is alot better than eclipse